# jquery should be able to fetch the contents of the table of 9000 rows on ONCLICK check box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i need a simple example where the jquery should be able to fetch the contents of the table where contents of the table will be more than 9000 rows.So when ONCLICK of respective table row check box should be able to display all the **checked** checkbox table row contents in the same view page. how to achieve this . explain with a simple example.. thanks for ur time.
[image]

as shown in the image so onclick of the last checkbox it should be able to display the contents of the table row..later when i click on submit it should be able to display all the contents

Comment: I'm not understanding what is the question...

Comment: Can you please simplify your question? I mean I am not able to interpret your words

Comment: ok one min... will explain u in brief

Comment: Grabbing 9000 rows at once might be a bad idea. You probably want to implement some sort of paging.

Comment: not all the 9000 rows..only the selected one tats the checked ones

Comment: This is simple enough for you if you know the basics of web applications architecture and how ajax and jquery works. There are to many sites to study the basics.

Answer (score 0):

So you can write something like this

```
$('input.checkBoxClass').live('click', function () {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "some.php",
               data: "id=" + $(this).attr('id'),
               success: function(msg){
               alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               }
          });
     }
});
```

Here I am assuming that your checkboxes are having class as checkBoxClass to ease the retrieval of checkboxes , you can use other selector.

live() method will listen to all the click events, you can write live block in $(document).ready() thing.

Also I am assuming you will assign primary key in id of checkbox.

Hopefully I was clear enough